# Win7: Is there some trick to speed up display a folder's content or the right click menu?

Tags: windows-7, performance-tuning

I'm using Windows 7 SP1, now whenever I click on a folder, the File Explorer takes quite some time to display the content inside; also when I right click on a file, the menu also comes quite slow.

Are there any particular ways to speed up these?

Comment: Any third-party shell extensions in the mix?

Comment: provide a xperf trace of the slow folder display or right click: http://pastebin.com/9R3Ehbs3

Comment: have you captured the trace or not?

Comment: Scandisk found 32MB bad sector and after its fixing, windows still alert hard disk issue, so I'm just to reinstall the OS, maybe replace a new HDD. @magicandre1981

Comment: ok, so your other issue is also caused by this HDD issue: http://superuser.com/questions/875424/windows-7-becomes-unberable-slow-what-could-i-do

Comment: @magicandre1981 exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common issue with *slow right-click handling* in Explorer is a context-menu with too many items. Many programs add themselves to Windows Explorer context menus, such as CCleaner and 7-Zip. Get rid of those used infrequently, either from the individual program options or with a tool such as Sysinternals Autoruns, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902 or Nirsoft's ShellMenuView, http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html, and ShellExView, http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html. 
Another possible issue is a large number of New items on right click; Nisoft has a utility for that, too: ShellMenuNew, http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_new.html.

As mentioned by Erlis D., above, thumbnails slow display of video and graphic files, such as JPEG, MP4 etc.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you are running into a problem, or just you want to speed things a bit. Anyway, for tips how to speed up things, I will make the text in italic. 
This depends also on your system specs, but still there could be some windows problems. It could also be a virus. For windows to generate thumbnails, it's needed some time for that. Only in case those thumbnails are generated before, and are in the thumbnails cache, the content shouldn't take at all to load. You can check if this happens, or if it takes a lot to load even after you open and reopen a folder. If it always takes a lot, most probably it's a virus. 
Now, that could be a problem also if you installed a codec with a bug (or maybe a thumbnail generator in general). Try to uninstall them (if you have any), and install one as [K-Lite Code](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm), which has a tool to generate thumbnails also. But this will be only valid for video thumbnails. As for other thumbnails, they get generated by programs which files are opened by default on windows. If the problem happens on any type of file, *than you can try to disable thumbnails* by pressing `Alt` key and going on `Tools` on the menu bar, and `Folder Options` - View Tab, and select 'Always show icons, never thumbnails' and apply changes. This will speed things up, but you will not see thumbnails anymore. 
*To remove, add, or organize your context menu*, check out [this tutorial](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/did-you-know-you-could-customize-the-windows-context-menu-organize-it-with-right-click-enhancer/), and for a more detailed or advanced one, [check this one](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-clean-up-your-messy-windows-context-menu/).
P.S.
Please let me know if you still need help...